# Translate existing Rails database into seed data file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to build a seed data file from an existing mysql database?

I know how to populate a new database with all the tables from an existing database. I'm curious if its possible to build a seed file (seed.rb) from a db.

Answer (score 3):

Try this https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

Should provide all the abilities you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are [a few gems](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/activerecord-seeds-ruby) for the purpose of extracting seeds from an existing database. You could try [**seed_dump**](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/zenprogrammer/seed_dump), for instance.